# Eckmann-Hilton argument / Grothendieck

Tags: ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, ho.history-overview

In terse terms, the “Eckmann-Hilton argument” says that a monoid in the category of monoids is commutative. It is essentially used, for example, to prove that homotopy groups of topological groups are commutative — more generally, that homotopy groups of H-spaces are commutative, in particular, higher homotopy groups are commutative.

This argument takes its name from its appearance in a 1962 Eckmann-Hilton paper (Group-like structures in general categories, I. Multiplications and comultiplications, *Mathematische Annalen*, June 1962, Volume 145, Issue 3, pp 227–255) but stems, it seems, from previous work from the same authors (*Homotopy and duality*, 1959).

It also appears explicitly in algebraic geometry, in Grothendieck's 1961 SGA 1 seminar *Revêtements étales et groupe fondamental,* devoted to the theory of the fundamental group of schemes. Namely, in Exposé XI (Examples and complements), Section 2 (Abelian varieties), Grothendieck writes (bottom of page 287 of the Springer-Verlag edition) : “On the other hand, since the functor $X\mapsto \pi_1(X)$ from pointed schemes $X$ to groups commutes with product, it transforms a group in the first category to a group in the category of groups, i.e., a commutative group.”

Does anybody know whether the two groups of people were aware of one another? Was this categorical argument already clear at that time ?

Comment: Where's this stated in SGA I?

Comment: Exposé XI (Exemples et compléments), section 2 (Variétés abéliennes), bottom of p. 287 (Springer edition) : « le foncteur $X  \mapsto \pi_1(X)$ transforme un groupe dans la première catégorie dans un groupe dans la catégorie des groupes, i.e. en un groupe commutatif. »

Comment: I might note in view of the connection between the Eckmann-Hilton argument and  the Godement relation that Roger Godement and Grothendieck were close friends.

Comment: Carlo, what do you mean with “the Godement relation” ?

Comment: Godement relation: https://books.google.nl/books?id=d1JTtOqBU6oC&pg=PA23

Comment: There is a somewhat obscure article by Dan Kan from 1958 ("On monoids and their dual", Bull Soc Math Mexcana) which appears to prove more or less the same result: that monoid objects in groups are abelian groups.  (At least according to MathSciNet, as the article isn't easily available to me.)

Comment: The first time that I saw the usage of the name "Godement operations" was in "À la poursuite des champs". Now I wonder how Roger Godement fits into the $\infty$-groupoid history.

Comment: I think you need $X/k$ or $Y/k$ proper for $\pi_1(X \times_k Y) = \pi_1(X) \times \pi_1(Y)$ (see [SGA1], X.1.7). Will Sawin mentioned in a comment in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/306353/group-over-algebraic-curves-having-genus-greater-than-1/ non-proper counterexamples in characteristic $p > 0$.

Comment: This is related to the fact that higher homotopy groups $\pi_n(X,x)$ are abelian for $n > 1$, as was shown by E. Cech in  in his presentation on these groups in the 1932 ICM at Z\" u rich, and led to his paper being withdrawn as they were not an acceptable generalisation of the fundamental group.